# pip with virtualenv requires sudo

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, sudo, fish

I'm on OSX and have a python `virtualenv` set up through `virtualfish` called `ds-mapreduce-env`. With the `venv` activated in my project directory it looks like the correct `pip` and `python` are chosen:

```
~/d/ds-mapreduce (venv) master ➜ which pip
/Users/cody/.virtualenvs/ds-mapreduce-env/bin/pip
~/d/ds-mapreduce (venv) master ➜ which python
/Users/cody/.virtualenvs/ds-mapreduce-env/bin/python
```

But when I run `pip install` it doesn't install to the virtual environment as expected. However, when I use `sudo` it does.

```
~/d/ds-mapreduce (venv) master ➜ pip install geonamescache
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): geonamescache in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

~/d/ds-mapreduce (venv) master ➜ sudo pip install geonamescache
The directory '/Users/cody/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/cody/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting geonamescache
Installing collected packages: geonamescache
Successfully installed geonamescache-0.18
```

I'm guessing this is some kind of permissions issue but I can't figure it out. I installed `python` with `brew install python` and `virtualfish` with `pip install virtualfish`. I tried removing and re-installing to no effect.

**My Solution**

My issue was with my `PYTHONPATH`. I had `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` prepended to my `PYTHONPATH`. Removing it fixed the issue!

Comment: did you create the virtualenv as root?  (does root own the folder "/Users/cody/.virtualenvs/ds-mapreduce-env")

Comment: no not as root: `drwxr-xr-x  7 cody  staff   238B Jun 22 12:23 ds-mapreduce-env`

Comment: Hi Cody. Does my answer here help address your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to uninstall the globally-installed package:

```
pip uninstall -y geonamescache
```

Confirm that it has been fully removed by inspecting `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. If not, manually remove any related detritus that you find there.

The next step is to better isolate your virtual environments' `site-packages` from your global `site-packages`. Add the following to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
set -x PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV "true"
```

If you open a new terminal session, you should now get an error if you run `pip install geonamescache` without an activated virtual environment — which is what we want. Create and activate a new virtual environment via `vf new ds-mapreduce-env` and try the same `pip install geonamescache` invocation again, and the package should be installed into the virtual environment.

Since this will prevent you from installing anything into your global `site-packages`, you may want to set up an alias that allows you to override this isolation and perform global `pip` operations. Add the following function as `~/.config/fish/functions/gpip.fish`:

```
function gpip -d "Manage globally-installed Python packages"
    env PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip $argv
end
```

With that in place, you can (for example) upgrade your global packages via:

```
gpip install --upgrade setuptools pip wheel virtualenv
```

Most of the above is already addressed via [Tacklebox](https://github.com/justinmayer/tacklebox) + [Tackle](https://github.com/justinmayer/tackle) (look for the `pip` plugin), which are projects designed to easily add enhancements to your `fish` environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Justin. I haven't tried this solution as I fixed the problem myself (see edit above).

Comment: Liked the switch to restrict pip to virtualenv.